# Change a parameter type of a Lodash function

Tags: arrays, typescript, lodash

I'm newbie to `Lodash` and I use it within `TypeScript` coding. So I have an array of objects called `items` (of foods), every `item` has a `category` object parameter (with `id` & `name` attributes), so it looks like this :

[image]

I want to group those `items` by **categroy names**, I've created a new Object of type `any` called `foodLists` (***public foodLists: any;***),
and after loading those items, I've tried this:

```
this.foodLists = lodash.keyBy(this.items, 'category.name');
```

Actually, it did a part of the work, so it appears like this:

[image: enter code here]

So the items are sorted by category , the issue is that it afftected **just an only** item to each category , however I want that many items should be affected to each category
So the second parameter of `lodash.keyBy()` (which is here `'category.name'`) should accept an array of objects. Hope you understand me. Is that possible ? or is there any alternative in lodash that gives the wanted result ? and Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it seems the solution is `_.groupBy`

```
lodash.groupBy(this.items, 'category.name')
```